# Get initial preview

Tags: javascript, bootstrap-file-upload

I am trying to use Krajee's bootstrap fileinput plugin (https://plugins.krajee.com/file-preview-management-demo#) to upload and preview my images, only I can not get the initial rendering via a get call on my server.

I would like the initialPreview property to be filled with my json that I get upstream

```
<input id="input-id" type="file" class="file file-preview-image file-preview-text" data-preview-file-type="text" multiple="multiple">
```

```
$("#input-id").fileinput({

        initialPreview: [
            "<img src = '" + value.url + "' style='width:213px;height:141px;' title = '" + value.name + "'>",

        ],
    });
```

```
0: {name: "56293/small/Capture_du_2019-07-17_10-32-20.png", size: 170871, url: "/image/view/dev_bao-hosts-images/56293%2Fsmall%2FCapture_du_2019-07-17_10-32-20.png"}
1: {name: "56293/small/groupe_160_a_suppr.png", size: 55003, url: "/image/view/dev_bao-hosts-images/56293%2Fsmall%2Fgroupe_160_a_suppr.png"}
2: {name: "56293/small/groupe_160_a_suppr_2.png", size: 55652, url: "/image/view/dev_bao-hosts-images/56293%2Fsmall%2Fgroupe_160_a_suppr_2.png"}
3: {name: "56293/small/mail_ouv-ferm.png", size: 146773, url: "/image/view/dev_bao-hosts-images/56293%2Fsmall%2Fmail_ouv-ferm.png"}
4: {name: "56293/small/paysage.jpg", size: 38491, url: "/image/view/dev_bao-hosts-images/56293%2Fsmall%2Fpaysage.jpg"}
5: {name: "56293/small/supervise.png", size: 64651, url: "/image/view/dev_bao-hosts-images/56293%2Fsmall%2Fsupervise.png"}
6: {name: "56293/small/test_gestionnaire.png", size: 37856, url: "/image/view/dev_bao-hosts-images/56293%2Fsmall%2Ftest_gestionnaire.png"}
7: {name: "56293/small/test_suppr.png", size: 55851, url: "/image/view/dev_bao-hosts-images/56293%2Fsmall%2Ftest_suppr.png"}
8: {name: "56293/small/test_suprr_2.png", size: 55575, url: "/image/view/dev_bao-hosts-images/56293%2Fsmall%2Ftest_suprr_2.png"}
9: {name: "56293/small/unsupervised.png", size: 64860, url: "/image/view/dev_bao-hosts-images/56293%2Fsmall%2Funsupervised.png"}
```

I suspect that I have to loop with an each to display this but I do not see how to forward it to initialPreview

Thanking you for your help!

Comment: Are the images uploaded by user or you are getting them from json? It's unclear what you are trying to do.

Comment: Its my json response for initial Preview  (if there are already images)

Comment: What is the purpose of the input?

Comment: In fact the plugin is used to send images, videos, documents with a preview of these, but it is also possible to display images by default. My goal is to display the images already sent to the server in the initialPreview property that accepts entries of the type:

<img src = "/img/img1.png"  title = "Image">
<img src = "/img/img2.png"  title = "Image2">